# How to get filename only without path in windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, script, batch

```
for /r %f in (*) do echo %f
```

Gives the output filename along with the entire path

```
\path\to\dir\<filename>
```

How do i get just the `<filename>` without the path included? I need to use that 'filename' string.

Also, is it possible to do the following, once the filename is acquired?

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
echo "blah blah blah 'filename'" >> blahblah_filename.txt
)
```

Comment: For future reference, Microsoft has an online [Windows XP - Command-line reference A-Z](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) which is still mostly applicable to later versions. The documentation in the answer you accepted is at the end of the section on the [`for`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Comment: @martineau: Unfortunately, the online 'Windows XP - Command-line reference A-Z' page is no longer on-line (removed by microsoft) and an alternative for this documentation is not yet available (as far as I can find any codumentation on '%~' argument documentation)

Comment: @PapaAtHome: Fortunately one can still view the command line reference via web.archive.org's [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20171221104755/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Use `%~nxf` for `<filename>.<extension>`.

And yes, you can do:

```
for /r %%f in (*) do (
echo "blah blah blah '%%~nxf'" >> blahblah_%%~nxf.txt
)
```

See `for /?`:

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~dpI       - expands %I to a drive letter and path only
    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
    %~fsI       - expands %I to a full path name with short names only
    %~dp$PATH:I - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable for %I and expands to the
                   drive letter and path of the first one found.
    %~ftzaI     - expands %I to a DIR like output line

In the above examples %I and PATH can be replaced by other valid
values.  The %~ syntax is terminated by a valid FOR variable name.
Picking upper case variable names like %I makes it more readable and
avoids confusion with the modifiers, which are not case sensitive.
```

Comment: Great answer. Any idea how I could search for a substring in a full path? For example, I want to know if c:\code\myapp\.git\somefolder includes the text ".git".

Comment: You can perform a textual or regex search by piping the path into the `find` or `findstr` command, e.g. `echo %%f | find "\.git\" > NUL` or `echo %%f | findstr /R /C:"\\\.git\\" /C:"\\\.git\>" > NUL` and then checking the errorlevel with the `if` command. (findstr regex is very limited, so that's my attempt at enforcing a leading ``\`` and [either a trailing ``\`` or end of string]). Do note that `if errorlevel` has quirks with fall-through, and you probably can't `if %errorlevel%` within a loop so you might need to `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` first and then `if !errorlevel!` instead.

Comment: @DaleBarnard Also, consider using PowerShell - much *much* less pain and probably more consistent results.

Comment: The blah blah is confusing me, what is it supposed to represent? How does the full path of the file and the extracted file name fit into this answer?

Comment: @thebunnyrules `%~nxf` is the filename, as I said in the first sentence. When you use it within a batch file, you need to double up the `%`, making it `%%~nxf`. The `blah blah blah` is just taking the example in the question and replacing the `filename` bit with the `%%~nxf` substitution - the `blah`s are just filler and have no particular meaning.

Comment: NOTE: These expansions also work on command line arguments. e.g., `pushd %~dp0` or `cd %~dp0` puts you in the directory where the batch file lives.  If your first batch file argument is a full path, then `set DIR=%~dp1` gives you the directory of that path, and `set FIL=%~nx1` gives you the filename and extension of that path.

Comment: when you use `%~n0` as argument, don't forget to quote it ( `"%~n0"` ) if it contains space (or it each part separated by space will count as a different arg)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not yet able to comment, but I believe the following should be noted to avoid confusion.

While `f` can be used as a FOR variable name, it's best to use another letter to avoid confusing it with format letter `f` (which, as stated in Bob's answer, returns full path name), or at least use a capital `F`.