# I want to get only the Filename in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, script, batch

I have a problem: I want to get the filename only from this path line in Command Prompt

Here's my path:

```
\\jktfile-01\lsmk\SRP\BankPelapor\201209\Instance\2882000-2012-09-30-BSMS26.xml
```

What kind of command should I do?

I already tried this solution [How to get filename only without path in windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/489240/how-to-get-filename-only-without-path-in-windows-command-line)

but it didn't work...

Comment: Please describe exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dir /b \\jktfile-01\lsmk\SRP\BankPelapor\201209\Instance\*.xml

will output

> 2882000-2012-09-30-BSMS26.xml

along with all other .xml files.

Not 100% sure what you are asking for though.

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for `dir /b \\jktfile-01\lsmk\SRP\BankPelapor\201209\Instance\2882000-2012-09-30-BSMS26.xml`, which will output just `2882000-2012-09-30-BSMS26.xml`.

Comment: @Scott Yep i want to get the file name from the line of link that i got, thx