# Batch script with FOR /R and ECHO don't work

Tags: command-line, batch

The script below don't work, it doesn't create the file with the ECHO command.
If I run the FOR line (changing %% by %) in CMD it's working perfectly.
Do you know why ?

```
SET TXTDATDIR=c:\TEST\EXPORT
SET LOGDIR=c:\TEST\EFALOG
SET TOPDIR=c:\TEST\EFALOG\TOP
IF NOT EXIST %TXTDATDIR%\*.* (
   IF EXIST %LOGDIR%\*.log (
      FOR /R %LOGDIR%\ %%f in (*.log) DO (
          ECHO T > %TOPDIR%\%%~nxf
      )
   )
)
```

I'm referring to this example : [How to get filename only without path in windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/489240/how-to-get-filename-only-without-path-in-windows-command-line?newreg=fba5892e280246f7bcdca1fc09d20c82)

Comment: "don't work" in what way exactly?

Comment: the ECHO T > %TOPDIR%\%%~nxf is suposed to write in a new file who have the same name as every *.log file in c:\TEST\EFALOG

Comment: Your code works here exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: Thanks David, I will do more test because in my case it seems to never enter in the FOR loop.