# Windows cmd.exe - How to prevent overwriting of output files while ffmpeg recursively processes a directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, video, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I'm trying to have `ffmpeg` iterate through a folder recursively and pull stills from multiple different video clips.

If I run:

```
for /r "W:\Exports\1 - Dailies\" %f in (*.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vf fps=6/60 still%05d.jpg
```

`ffmpeg` will pull a still every 10 seconds from the first `.mov` file it encounters, but then when it moves onto the second `.mov` file, the count for `still%05d.jpg` restarts to `still00001.jpg` and the stills from the second file overwrite the stills from the first file. Then the stills from the third file overwrite the second, and so on and so forth.

How can I prepend the filename of the input file to the filename of the output JPG files so that no overwriting occurs?

Comment: `%f` contains the filename, so use `"%fstill%05d.jpg"`

Comment: @DavidPostill If I try that, I get the following error: `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'W:\Exports\1'
W:\Exports\1: Invalid argument`

Comment: `%f` will hold drive,path,name,extension, use `%f~n`

Comment: Indeed. What @LotPings said.

Comment: Close, but turns out it was actually `%~nf`. Found that from this: https://superuser.com/a/489242/452924

Comment: `-n` can be added to have ffmpeg abort when output file already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/489242/452924) that I could use `%~nf`:

```
for /r "W:\Exports\1 - Dailies\" %f in (*.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%f" -vf fps=6/60 %~nf_still%05d.jpg
```