# Can I move hundreds of pdf's into separate folders with the same name, at one time?

Tags: windows-10, adobe-acrobat

I have a folder with 500 PDF's all named WP-001, WP-002, WP-003...etc.  I also have another folder with 500 separate folders with the exact same names.  Without downloading any software (my company wont allow it)...is there an easy way to add the PDF's to their corresponding folders at one time?

Comment: Where are you moving them to? To another hard disk, USB? Yes you should be able to pick-up the one folder with a right-click (holding onto it), and dropping it somewhere, say hard disk E:, and letting go. There should be a _context message box_ which asks you to copy or move the item(s). Choose _move_.

Comment: Yes, you can but it depends on the tools you have available. You could do it with a simple powershell script or cmd script.

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed access to **PowerShell**:

```
$Source   = 'c:\SourceFolder'
$DestRoot = 'c:\DestinationWithSubfolders'
Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter *.pdf | Move-Item - Destination { Join-Path $DestRoot $_.BaseName }
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)
[Move-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item?view=powershell-7)
[Join-Path](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 1):

The following `.bat` file, launched with the source folder as the current folder,
should do the job:

```
for /r %%f in (*.pdf) do copy "%%f" "C:\path\to\target\%%~nf\%%~nxf"
```

References:

- [FOR /F command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
  section "Parameter Extensions"
- [How to get filename only without path in windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/489240/how-to-get-filename-only-without-path-in-windows-command-line)