# Any way to copy only all the files in a folder, without the folders?

Tags: robocopy

Any way to copy only all the files in a folder, without the folders?

I tried these to no avail (they copy folders too):

```
ROBOCOPY D:\SAMPLE D:\SAMPLE2 /IF *.* /E

ROBOCOPY D:\SAMPLE D:\SAMPLE2 *.* /E
```

any help much appreciated

Comment: Open cmd, navigate to the Sample folder and use `for /r %d in (*) do copy "%d" "D:\SAMPLE2\"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell to copy files/certain files without having to copy folders
Please check this example :

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter "*.txt" $source |
  Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -gt (get-date -date "2018-12-01 00:00:00") } |
  Copy-Item -Destination $target
```

This runs `Get-ChildItem` recursively, looking only for files matching the filter `*.txt` or any files type. Afterwards the result is filtered by the `LastAccessTime` attribute of the file and only files newer than date X are kept. The result of that is piped into `Copy-Item`.
Of course, you can also run GUI tools like Syncback or Gs Richcopy instead, but that becomes pretty easy and free .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if or how this could be achieved by Robocopy, but with plain Batch (Windows CMD shell) you could try something like:

`mkdir d:\sample2`

`for /f %f in ('dir /s /b d:\sample') do (copy /y "%f" "d:\sample2\%~xnf")`

(Answer partially taken from here: https://superuser.com/a/489242/1691896)

Comment: could you please include the paths to source and target folders?  I tried navigating first to the source folder to no avail.  Thank you

Comment: @Antonio23249, okay, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I can't make that work.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: What's the exact error you get?